# Django ORM queries. How to convert sql to ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following sql statement and I want to refactor it to ORM but don't know how left join works when we have no foreign keys between two tables. It basically checks table sag_diff for new businessLines. It insert only new ones to table BusinessLines.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_BusinessLines 
( BusinessLine_Name, Run_Date ) 
SELECT DISTINCT 
tbl_SAG_Diff.BUSINESS_LINE, tbl_SAG_Diff.Run_Date 
FROM tbl_SAG_Diff 
LEFT JOIN tbl_BusinessLines 
ON tbl_SAG_Diff.BUSINESS_LINE = tbl_BusinessLines.BusinessLine_Name 
WHERE((tbl_BusinessLines.BusinessLine_Name)IS null);
```

here are my models:

```
class BusinessLines(models.Model):

    BusinessLine_ID=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    BusinessLine_Name=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    run_date = models.DateField(null=True)

class SAG_diff(models.Model):

    Business_Line = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    RUN_DATE = models.DateField(null=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run raw SQL queries with Django's ORM if that's what you wanted. You don't have to change your query in that case, you can check documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries